# How to create a variable size char array in VC++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, mfc

```
const int sizea = 600; 
char sz[sizea];
```

above code works fine. But below code segment cause errors.
I'm working on visual studio 2005 - MFC application

```
CString strFinal;

.......//strFinal value is dynamically changing . . 

const int size = strFinal.GetLength();
char sz[size];
```

> Error 2   error C2057: expected constant expression
>   Error 5   error C2070: 'char []': illegal sizeof operand
>   Error 4   error C2133: 'sz' : unknown size     Error  3   error C2466: cannot allocate an array of
>   constant size 0

Comment: Are you compiling this as C, or as C++? They are not the same.

Comment: can't you use a std::vector ? it can be used to pass to legacy functions that receive arrays.

Comment: size should be a compile time constant...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the current version of C++, arrays must have a fixed size, specified by a compile-time constant. If you need to use a run-time value, then your options are:

- most portably, use a dynamic array class such as `std::string` or `std::vector<char>`;
- use a compiler that supports C99 variable-length arrays as a non-standard extension;
- wait a year for dynamic arrays to (hopefully) be introduced in C++14 (and perhaps wait a bit longer for your compiler vendor to catch up).

Comment: Mike i'm using MFC in VC++

Comment: @ANjaNA: OK, I've removed the C tag to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Normal use-case is to use `new` (and `delete` when you're done) for variable-sized elements.  If you *must* use the stack, you can use `alloca`.

```
char *psz = new char[size+1];  // +1 you probably want zero-termination
...
delete [] psz;
```

Comment: The normal way is to use something like a `std::vector`.

Comment: @chris... yes, true as well... had my mind stuck in C there for a moment

Comment: [This link also spell the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312116/c-array-size-dependent-on-function-parameter-causes-compile-errors?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

you can use vector as a dynamic array. Try this.

```
#include <vector> // use this header
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; // use this namespace

int main()
{
    vector<int> v; //declare dynamic array equivalent

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        v.push_back(10 + i);
    }

    cout << "vector data: " << endl;
    print_collection(v);

    while (v.begin() != v.end()) { 
        cout << "v.back(): "; print_elem(v.back()); cout << endl;
        v.pop_back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It produces an error because `GetLength()` returns you an arbitrary value, not statically defined.

The proper way is to allocate enough memory to hold your string and, if required, the `NULL`-terminated symbol either by calling `malloc` or by using the `new` operator (if compiling with C++ compiler).

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this long time ago 
the Idea is to work with pointers.

so you need to make structure that has (char and nextPointer)
the char represent the current value of the array and the nextPointer represent the next structure of the series

looping all through that pointers u will have your array of whatever you want your structure connected

```
struct yourStructure {
  Char char;
  double nextPointer;
} ;
```

so you create first structure and connect to the second and the tree

[image]

Comment: This is a linked list and there is an overhead of connecting each node. Thanks